# Autosave with TinyMCE

Tags: wysiwyg

I have tried outputting code simliar to the custom_format example thats included with TinyMCE. I enabled the Autosave module, however I never see a "restore drafts" button. The only setting that doesn't wipe out all the buttons in the editor is using "theme_advanced_buttons3". Which also doesn't show a button with the 'restoredraft' value.

Edit: [context](http://www.tinymce.com/forum/viewtopic.php?pid=104607#p104607)

Answer (score 2):

I have made some progress on this. I downloaded the TinyAutoSave module from https://code.google.com/p/tinyautosave/ which I believe is more recent than the 'autosave' plugin included with TinyMCE 3.4.4. There may be updates in the latest version of tinymce, but I haven't checked. It seems the codebases have forked, however.

Anyways, I ended up removing autosave from the tinymce.inc file located in sites/all/libraries/wysiwyg/editors. I put tinyautosave/ into sites/all/libraries/tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/plugins.

The solution involved was to not use the 'restoredraft' setting, and use the 'tinyautosave' one instead. I have some strange way that builds the wysiwyg settings table but it basically does:

```
$settings['tinyautosave'] = array('tinyautosave' => 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

After searching a bit I found a [fixed issue](http://drupal.org/node/1409100) at drupal.org. A dev describes how it is possible to integrate thirdparty plugins with tinyautosave as an example.

I just did what was described and everything works fine for me now.